# Google Sheet - Privacy Settings

Tags: google-docs

Is it possible to hide others details in Google Spread Sheet?

I've a Google Sheet, which I want to share to others. Whoever has the link to access can enter data into it.

Users A, B, C are supposed to enter the data.

But whatever user A entered should not be visible to users B, C and vice versa.

Only the owner can view the details entered by users A, B, C.

Is it possible, if so how?

Comment: Not really programming related, flagged for migration to superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using only Google sheets.

However, you can create a Google form. Add questions using their interface, and get an url to a online form. Data entered into this form is inserted into a spreadsheet.